# SonarLint Warning: Reducing the cognitive complexity (16 instead of 15) for chunking an image

Tags: java, awt, complexity-theory, sonarlint

I have written a function whose aim is to take a collection of subimages defined from a rescaled input image (these subimages are called "rescaled chunks of the rescaled input image") and re-assemble these rescaled chunks into an output whole image (whose dimensions are those of the input image, rescaled). All chunks have the same dimensions.

The function is defined below. The problem is that SonarLint warns me that the cognitive complexity is 16 instead of 15, and I don't want to change this default SonarLint's limit. **What could I do?**

The function is described below the following code:

```
final BufferedImage reassembleChunksInASingleImage(final int inputImageWidth, final int inputImageHeight, final int scalingCoefficient, final int chunkWidth, final int chunkHeight, final List<BufferedImage> theChunks) {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Reassembling...");

    final int reassembled_chunks_image_width = scalingCoefficient * inputImageWidth;
    final int reassembledChunksImageHeight = scalingCoefficient * inputImageHeight;
    final int rescaled_chunk_width = scalingCoefficient * chunkWidth;
    final int rescaledChunkHeight = scalingCoefficient * chunkHeight;
    final BufferedImage reassembledChunksImage = new BufferedImage(reassembled_chunks_image_width, reassembledChunksImageHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    int indexOfTheChunkToUse = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < reassembled_chunks_image_width; i += rescaled_chunk_width) {
        for(int j = 0; j < reassembledChunksImageHeight; j += rescaledChunkHeight) {

            final BufferedImage chunkToUse = theChunks.get(indexOfTheChunkToUse);
            int iForDraw = i;
            int jForDraw = j;
            final int deltaI = reassembled_chunks_image_width - (i + rescaled_chunk_width);
            final int deltaJ = reassembledChunksImageHeight - (j + rescaledChunkHeight);
            if(deltaI < 0) {
                iForDraw -= Math.abs(deltaI);
            }
            if(deltaJ < 0) {
                jForDraw -= Math.abs(deltaJ);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < rescaled_chunk_width; x++) {
                for(int y = 0; y < rescaledChunkHeight; y++) {

                    int colorToDraw = chunkToUse.getRGB(x, y);
                    reassembledChunksImage.setRGB(iForDraw + x, jForDraw + y, colorToDraw);
                }
            }
            indexOfTheChunkToUse++;
        }
    }

    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Reassembling done.");
    return reassembledChunksImage;
}
```

- I go through the rescaled image, incrementing the horizontal or vertical shift with the adequat (x-axed or y-axed) dimension of the chunks (all chunks have the same dimension). The concerned loops are: `for(int i = 0; i < reassembled_chunks_image_width; i += rescaled_chunk_width) {for(int j = 0; j < reassembledChunksImageHeight; j += rescaledChunkHeight) {`
- I set the current rescaled image's pixel's color to the one of the current chunk. The concerned loops are: `for(int x = 0; x < rescaled_chunk_width; x++) {for(int y = 0; y < rescaledChunkHeight; y++) {`.
- If the current chunk is out of bounds of the rescaled image, I shift it to the left or to the top and then I draw it. The concerned controls are: `if(deltaI < 0) {if(deltaJ < 0) {`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to refactor your method e.g.

```
int iForDraw = getDraw(reassembled_chunks_image_width, rescaled_chunk_width, i);
int jForDraw = getDraw(reassembledChunksImageHeight, rescaledChunkHeight, j);
```

add a small method e.g. getDraw

```
private int getDraw(int reassembled_chunks_image_data, int rescaled_chunk_data, int index) {
    int result = index;
    int delta = reassembled_chunks_image_data - (index + rescaled_chunk_data);
    if (delta < 0) {
        result -= Math.abs(delta);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Ah yes thank you! However I prefered to create a new function only for drawing the chunk on the output image. It corresponds to: `for(int x = 0; x < rescaledChunkWidth; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < rescaledChunkHeight; y++) {`.